# ruby package loaded but not functional

Tags: ruby, bots, telegram

I've loaded a package in ruby but when I try to execute it, I get an error.
Please help!

Code:

```
require 'telegram/bot'

token = "REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_TOKEN"

Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|

end
```

Result:

```
undefined method `run' for Telegram::Bot::Client:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory:

> ```
> undefined method `run' for Telegram::Bot::Client:Class (NoMethodError)
> ```

The error message is telling you that the method `Telegram::Bot::Client::run` does not exist, and both the [documentation](https://rubydoc.info/github/telegram-bot-rb/telegram-bot/Telegram/Bot/Client), the [README](https://github.com/telegram-bot-rb/telegram-bot#client), and the [source code](https://github.com/telegram-bot-rb/telegram-bot/blob/master/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb) seem to agree that there is, indeed, no such method.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is not that your package is not loaded. But that **class method** `run` does not exist. You may want to check whether you have installed the latest version, not something old.

Other than that, I can hardly imagine what could be going on.